# How to utilize KeyEvent without creating a new public method?

Tags: java, keyevent

I am making a "maze game" in a beginning coding class at the moment, and I am having a hard time understanding the KeyEvent class.
I have a move method (incomplete) that is used to move an explorer throughout this maze based on keyboard input.

```
public void move(int key){



    int row = this.location().row();
    int col = this.location().col();



    if (getKeyChar() == VK_RIGHT)

        if (this.wall(RIGHT))
        {
            row += 1;
            this.moveTo(maze.getSquare(row, col));
        }




}
```

I know "if (getKeyChar() == VK_RIGHT)  is incorrect, and I understand how KeyEvent works in some other situations, but being a college course there are restrictions in place such as that the architecture of my code must match what my prof's testing files look for, which means I can not create a new public method aside from what is already in my code.

I have seen other possts such as the answer to [Detecting keyboard direction keys using keyPressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573918/detecting-keyboard-direction-keys-using-keypressed) but this involved a new public method which I cannot have.

I have also seen many uses of "KeyEvent(Component source, int id, long when, int modifiers, int keyCode)" but frankly I don't know what I would input for any of those arguments, and I don't believe this is what I am looking for.\

Though my instructor did not directly say we cannot, I believe I cannot use keyListener either.

I want to be able to check if a certain arrowkey is pressed, and if so, call a moveTo(Square s) function I have. If anyone can explain how this would work given my restrictions, that would be amazing.

Tried to be specific, sorry if this is a poor question, this is my first post ever, thanks in advanced!

Comment: KeyEvent in Swing/AWT is normally associated with KeyListener but I'd recommend that you use the key bindings API instead

Comment: You can also use an anonymous or inner class